# XSLT: Find the node having attribute value equal to another attribute from another node

Tags: xslt

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
    <TreeNode bbd="" id="TreeNodID" vid="VirtualID" />
    <ChildNode bbd="bbd1" date="2017-02-22T15:04:32Z" object="ChildNodeID"  thread="TreeNodID" />
</Root>`

I want to write an xslt which will rewrite the xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <TreeNode bbd="bbd1" id="TreeNodeID" vid="VirtualID" object="ChildNodeID" />
    <ChildNode bbd="bbd1" date=&quot;2017-02-22T15:04:32Z object="ChildNodeID" thread="TreeNodeID" />
</Root>
```

I want to find the node having `/*/@thread` attribute of any node equal to the value of `TreeNode/@id`. Get the value of `@object` attribute of the matching node and populate it in `TreeNode` element. Also get the `bbd` value and populate it in `TreeNode` element.

I am not aware of whether the matching node is `ChildNode` or something else.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is condition to move attribute from childnode to treenode

Comment: Learn how to use a **key**: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:aa="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="aa:TreeNode">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="bbd" select="//*[@thread eq $id]/@bbd"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[normalize-space(.) ne '']"></xsl:copy-of>
            <xsl:attribute name="object" select="//*[@thread eq $id]/@object"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Rupesh, due to presence of attribute xmlns in Root node it does not give the expected result...

Comment: define that namespace in xsl declaration or mention in your question for cheking

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: if you have namespace in your root than it s/b define as namespace like <Root xmlns:ABC="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">

Comment: The namespace is like that only. How to workaround if the namespace is going to like that only?

Answer (score 1):

I could do this using following xslt
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TreeNode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="/*/node()/@thread=@id">
                <xsl:attribute name="object">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/*/node()/@object"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>          
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`

The remaining portion is - if exists bbd then check if value is empty then add attribute and populate with the value, if already populated with some value then keep it as is.
otherwise add attribute and populate with the value.